# Creating Java EE web service which expects dynamic input

Tags: java, web-services, java-ee-5

I'm developing a web service which is very generic. This web service will validate the input (based on some configuration) and delegate the request to some third party web service based on the values in teh input. Since this web service is not handling most of the requests and is being delegated to others, the input to this web service will be very dynamic.
For example below is my web service method

```
public OutpuVO service (InputVO inputVO){
    //Validate the basic details

    //Delegate to another service.
}
```

Both `OutputVO` and `InputVO` extends from `BaseVO`. The structure of `InputVO` and `OuptuVO` is very dynamic. It all depends upon the data that the caller provides.

I have multiple questions regarding this.

1. How do we create the WSDL for this? Should we use 
   to provide the data?
2. How will the client be generated for this?

I'm not sure how the above will be done in this case. Can you please guide me? Kindly let me know if any further details needs to be provided.

Comment: See if this idea is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134538/multiple-xsd-mappings-in-webservice-is-that-possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you please provide some tutorials or examples on how to implement this? In my case there is no predefined structure for the input. I don't think I'll be able to generate separate wsdl for each client. Is it better to use CDATA in that case?